# Was IEqualityComparer<T> introduced for the following reasons?

Tags: c#

1) Are the reasons why `IEqualityComparer<T>` was introduced:

a) so we would be able to compare objects (of particular type) for equality in as many different ways as needed

b) and  by having a standard interface for implementing a custom equality comparison, chances are that much greater that third party classes will accept this interface as a parameter and by that allow us to inject into these classes equality comparison behavior via objects implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>`

2) I assume `IEqualityComparer<T>` should not be implemented on type `T` that we're trying to compare for equality, but instead we should implement it on helper class(es)?

Thank you

Comment: If you have two questions, ask two questions, not two rolled into one.

Comment: Noted. Will make sure next posts don't include multiple ( non-related ) questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doubtful that anyone here will be able to answer with any authority the *reason* that the interface was introduced (my guess--and that's all it is--would be to support one of the generic set types like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `HashSet<T>`), but its [purpose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) is clear:

> Defines methods to support the comparison of objects for equality.

If you combine this with the fact you can have multiple types implementing this interface (see [`StringComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx)), then the answer to question **a** is *yes*.

The reason for this is threefold:

1. Operators (in this case, `==`) are not polymorphic; if the type is upcasted to a higher level than where the type-specific comparison logic is defined, then you'll end up performing a reference comparison rather than using the logic within the `==` operator.
2. `Equals()` requires at least one valid reference and can provide different logic depending on whether it's called on the first or second value (one could be more derived and override the logic of the other).
3. Lastly and most importantly, the comparison logic provided by the type may not be what the user is after. For example, strings (in C#) are case sensitive when compared using `==` or `Equals`. This means that any container (like `Dictionary<string, T>` or `HashSet<string>`) would be case-sensitive. Allowing the user to provide another type that implements `IEqualityComparer<string>` means that the user can use whatever logic they like to determine if one string equals the other, including ignoring case.

As for question **b**, probably, though I wouldn't be surprised if this wasn't high on the list of priorities.

For your final question, I'd say that's generally true. While there's nothing stopping you from doing so, it is confusing to think that type `T` would provide custom comparison logic that is different from that provided on type `T` just because it's referenced as an `IEqualiltyComparer<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

1. agreed on a and b
2. "should not be" is always a normative question and rarely a good metric. You do what works without getting into trouble. (Pragmatic Programmer). The fact that you can implement the interface statefull, stateless and in any which way, makes it possible to implement (alternative) comparers for all types, including value types, enums, sealed types, even abstract types; In essence it is a Strategy pattern

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there's a *natural* equality comparison for a type, in which case it should implement `IEquatable<T>`, not `IEqualityComparer<T>`. At other times, there are multiple possible ways of comparing objects for equality - so it makes sense to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` then. It allows hash tables (and sets etc) to work in a flexible way.